# Efficiency comparation in `sync.Mutex`, `sync.Map`, and `atomic.Value`

Tags: performance, go, mutex, atomic, microbenchmark

When I compare efficiency of `sync.mu`, `sync.Map` and `atomic.Value` in go, expected that `sync.mu` is less efficient than latter two. But when I did a benchmark test, found that execution duration is less using `sync.mu`. So I want to know the reason or maybe there is a best practice.

**Code**

Source code is here https://go.dev/play/p/WODF8Tyyw4d Simplify it as follows:

- Scene1: Change a random kv pair in map, `sync.mu` vs `sync.Map`

```
// sync.mu reader
mu.Lock()
tmp := tA[idx]
mu.Unlock()
// sync.mu writer
mu.Lock()
tA[idx] = data
mu.Unlock()

// sync.Map reader
v, _ := tB.Load(idx)
// sync.Map writer
tB.Store(idx, data)
```

- Scene2: Change a whole map, `sync.mu` vs `atomic.Value`

```
// sync.mu reader
mu.Lock()
tmp := tA[0]
mu.Unlock()
// sync.mu Writer
mu.Lock()
tA = data
mu.Unlock()

// atomic.Value reader
v := tC.Load().(map[int]int)[0]
// atomic.Value writer
tC.Store(data)
```

**Result**

```
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: sync-demo
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
BenchmarkMu-12          1000000000               0.5401 ns/op
BenchmarkSyncMap-12     1000000000               0.5504 ns/op
BenchmarkMuTotal-12     1000000000               0.5418 ns/op
BenchmarkAtomic-12      1000000000               0.5457 ns/op
PASS
ok      sync-demo    64.195s
```

Comment: Code should be included in the question, and not linked to.

Comment: 0.5401 ns/op means the whole code got optimised away. You must not do this type of micro (or even **nano**) benchmarkrs unless you are an absolute ultracrack in this type of low level CPU/memory stuff. Your expectations where unfounded and your benchmarks badly designed. You are not going to learn from this kind of experiments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not conparing the efficiency of such sync structures, since you are also doind I/0. Also there are goroutines and waitgroups in this code … not sure if I understand it

You should consider compare similar usages in the same context.

For instance, increment a counter. You have a counter in a sync.Map, atomic.Value and protected by mutex.

There are pros and cons of each approach, but the mutex handle only synchronization while the others structures also handles storage.

Mutex should be faster because it is… less complex.

However, if you handle something more complex than an uint64 perhaps the overhead of atomic.Value may be ok.

For instance, using mutex you need a specific order of lock/unlock and you may find some issues without proper testing + race condition detector.

While atomic.Value handle this for you.

I never use sync.Map but I have very efficient code in production using atomic.Value - and I am ok with this.

The correct benchmark need a more technical approach.

Comment: thanks for your reply. In the benchmark code, I simulated a multi-RW scenario. Of course, there is I/O and multi-goroutines. I toke the total execution time as the evaluation criteria in this scenario, less means better. After many times, I got the same result. I wonder why `sync.mutex` is more simple but did better.

Comment: You can check the source code

Comment: Thank u for pointing out my mistake. I remove I/O ops and I get similar result. That looks like there's less difference in efficiency but the `sync.Map` and `atomic.Value` are more friendly.

Comment: @wanncy, note that `sync.Map` and `atomic.Value` are very different things, and only the former offers synchronization to enforce a “happens before” ordering. Also `sync.Map` specifically mentions that you probably want a map with a mutex in most cases (especially now that generics can be used for some extra polymorphism).